Why was my flag to an answer containing "advertisement content" declined?
I flagged an answer which contained advertisement to a certain website about coaching. The flag was declined. Nonetheless the answer was moved as a comment (which I don't have any problems with). However, the answer was later flagged as "spam or rude or abusive". It was accepted and that has led to getting that "answer"converted into a comment.



I have two queries:

Why was my flag declined when it had advertisement content? The "answer" could have moved to a comment then only (at least the first 3 (maybe 4) sentences).
Why it was later flagged "spam or rude or abusive" (and was accepted)? It was neither of them.


I had to do some digging to figure out the sequence of events (despite being the one who handled all of these), but I think I've pieced it together.

It looks like you accidentally flagged the question, rather than the answer; I declined the flag because of course the question of course isn't self-promotion (although there are other issues with it).
I actually didn't manually mark the two flags on the answer -- one as spam, one as not an answer -- as helpful. Instead, I directly converted the answer to a comment, which simultaneously automatically deletes the post. Because the post was deleted, the system also automatically marked the flags as helpful.

I probably should have manually declined the spam flag before doing anything else; fortunately, I think there was minimal harm done.

I am quite careful with raising flags, but if you say I accidently flagged the question instead of the answer, then it must be a mistake from my part (probably less coffee). And, yes there is no harm done. Just a small query from my side. Cheers!

@NilayGhosh Cheers -- I'm pretty sure this is what happened, but the interface could afford to be a little bit clearer about it. . .
